# Background with position fixed and size contain, relative to container

Tags: css

So I came across this today.

I have a section that is longer than the viewport, which has a background image with `background-attachment: fixed;`. This background is also using the `background-size: cover;` property. (needed for responsive purposes)

With the fixed position applied to the background, it crops off the image  to fit it within the current viewport height and overflows the top of the tag.

Is there a way to make the image sit in the correct place (i.e. same position as if it wasn't fixed) and maintain the cover propery.

```css
.hero {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1920-1920-1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  /* set the height of the hero. */
  height: 125vh;
}

.fixed {
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<h4>With the fixed position</h4>
<section class="hero fixed"></section>

<h4>Without the fixed position</h4>
<section class="hero"></section>
```

I'm guessing as fixed elements are fixed to the viewport, the answer is no, but wasn't sure as it's a background image.
I wondered if perhaps anyone has found a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that the background area is fixed to 100% view port if you use fixed - You can enlarge the background area by adding background-size:

```
.hero {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1920-1920-1.jpg);
  /*background-size: cover;*/
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  /* set the height of the hero. */
  background-size: 125vh;
  height: 125vh;
}
```